# media seems to not calculate the screen size properly

Tags: html, css, firefox, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive index for my website, for this, i'm using Firefox Responsive Design Mode. In 1920x900px, my @media is working perfectly. The problem is when i change to 1280x600px. He keeps getting the images positioning like i order in 1920x900px. I made some tests and other attributes for 1280x600px works ! Here's the comments in my code:

```
/* Para monitores 1280x600px */
@media screen and (max-height:600px){
    #slider{
       /* If i change this to display:none; it really disappear the tag,
        which makes me guess the screen calc is doing ok.*/
        height:73.5vh;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1280px){
    #mainAtc{
        margin-left:2vw;
    }

    #othAtc{
        margin-left:0;
    }
}

/* Para monitores 1920x900px */
@media screen and (max-height: 900px){
    #slider{
        /* But, if in 1280x600 i got display:none, and here i got display:block, he shows me the image. It's like it doesn't work just when i give same attributes to differente @media. */
        height:51.6vh;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1920px){
    #mainAtc{
        margin-left:2vw;
    }

    #othAtc{
        margin-left:7.6vw;
    }

    #atcRest{
        margin-left:2vw;
    }
}
```

Someone could help me ? Thanks!

Comment: try setting a min-width for 1920x900px `(min-width: 1281px) and (max-width: 1920px)` same for height

Comment: Indeed that's the most inteligent thing to do ! Thanks !